# WooCommerce > Orders > Order Notes: This FIRST note is not sent, THE REST ARE SENT CORRECTLY

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I send a note to a customer from the WooCommerce > Orders page, only the first note is not sent, but the rest are sent correctly.

What could it be?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Messages are always sent, but they fall into the spam folde rsometimes